# MyLocationOverlay change the marker to the Google Maps default

Tags: java, android, google-maps, mapactivity

I'm investigating MapActivities, and what I'm attempting to do is to change the default marker of MyLocationOverlay from the default circle to the marker that google maps uses (the blue arrow head)
Is there any easy way of doing that? thanks in advance
Here is an image with the current default maker
http://blogs.conchango.com/photos/conchango_bloggers/images/13878/original.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to draw the circle by yourself using `onDraw()` method of subclass of `Overlay`.
Here is a [**Draw A Circle On Android MapView**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293709/draw-a-circle-on-android-mapview) post how to do that.

And when talking about `blue arrow head`
There is a list of drawable which are packaged in `Android.jar`. You can access the using their ids, (if they are public) something like:

```
android.R.any_id
```

Have a look at this [page](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/). specifically at `ic_maps_indicator_current_position`