# Drawing a circle on MapView with specifiec radius on Monondroid

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm trying  to draw a circle with specific radius in km (for example 2km) on a MapView at specific lat/lng. I've found some samples:

[Creating Custom Overlay on the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428730/creating-custom-overlay-on-the-map)

[Draw A Circle On Android MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293709/draw-a-circle-on-android-mapview)

[Draw circle of certain radius on map view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029529/draw-circle-of-certain-radius-on-map-view-in-android)

I think first and second of above are useful but these are in Java and I need code for Mono for Android (Monodevelop).

I can't find Projection class in monodroid.
And can't use `com.google.android.maps.Projection`.
Can somebody help me how to use these codes in monodroid?

Answer (score 0):

[`com.google.android.maps.Projection`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/Projection) is an interface, so it is made available in Mono for Android as [`Android.GoogleMaps.IProjection`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aAndroid.GoogleMaps.IProjection) to keep with normal C# conventions.

Similarly, where you'd use mapView.getProjection() in Java, in C# it is made available via the [`Projection` property on `MapView`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=P%3aAndroid.GoogleMaps.MapView.Projection#).

Xamarin has [some tutorials on their site](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Maps_and_Location/Part_2_-_Maps_API#Custom_Drawn_Overlays) that go over how to use these to create custom overlays, so I'd suggest checking them out.